# Substitute of WaitForSingleObject

Tags: c++, multithreading

I used multi-thread on a deblocking algorithm.
With no thread, it runs 30ms.
With 40 threads, it runs 40ms around.
However, in my observation, 20ms of the 40ms are used in WaitForSingleObject.

I want to know, are there any work around of the WaitForSingleObject.

EDIT:
My problem consists of two loops. The second one rely on the result of the first one.
I use four threads for each loop. Each thread run a quarter of that loop's content.

I need to wait for the 1st loop's four thread to finish before I start the next 4 threads for the
second loop.

But I'm feeling the WaitForSingleObject takes too much time.
The slowest thread only costs 1 to 2 ms.
but in my recording, the WaitFor singleObject takes somewhat the same.

With no thread, it's almost the same speed or even slower sometimes.
  So, in my case, threading really helps to accelerate, but the WaitForSingleObject eats up 
all the saved time and make the programme as slow as one thread.

Comment: Did you try looking at the MSDN page for WaitForSingleObject?

Comment: This might require more details about your problem and the solutions you've already tried.

Comment: I did learn how to use this function on MSDN page. But I didn't find hints of a lighter substitution. I'm reading of criticalSection as zr. recommended

Comment: Odd, the second line of [the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) provides a suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean WaitForMultipleObjectsEx, but this don't save time than WaitForSingleObject. I even tried using a global counter to wait for all threads to exit,  while (globalCounter < 4) ;
not much improvement. I think maybe multithreading don't suit calculation that use little time (mine 30ms)

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject` is not at fault here - the call simply waits for a thread to finish. You can either rethink your multithreading strategy, offloading more work to spare cores, if any - so that neither wastes time waiting for another, or you simply wait like you do now. Synchronization adds to total processing time, per Amdahls Law. Once again, refactor code to get rid of synchronization or accept it.

Comment: @RobertBean - 30ms is fine. The latency of WFSO on inter-thread comms is typically around 2-20us, so I suspect your design is less-than-optimal :(  Are you continually creating/terminating/destroying these threads, or keeping them around and signaling/waiting them when required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EnterCriticalSection and LeaveCriticalSection are much lighter sync primitives. You should prefer these over other locks whenever possible.

EDIT (following EDIT in question): You can use the [Windows API Barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is probably with performance that is good as the EnterCriticalSection

Comment: Critical sections are faster if contention is rare. But in the scenario described above, contention is guaranteed.